# Getting a NullPointerException when trying to insert using SQL

Tags: java, sql, connection

I've been trying to insert values into my database using Java.
Here is the code that i first tried.

```
Connection conn = null;
        if(action.getSource() == btnAddItem) 
        {
            String command =
                    "INSERT INTO item VALUES (" + itemNo + ", " 
                            + itemName + ", " 
                            + costprice + ", " 
                            + sellingprice + ", " 
                            + stock + ")";

            try 
            {
                this.executeInsert(conn, command); //works
                //testPrint(command);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I checked saperately using the testPrint method to see if there was an issue in the string command. But that method worked fine. The  executeInsert did not. Here is the `executeInsert` method i used:

```
public boolean executeInsert(Connection connection, String command) throws SQLException
{
        try
        {
          Statement st = connection.createStatement();
          st.executeUpdate(command);
          connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Got an exception!");
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;


    }   
}
```

Since that didn't work i went through a few tutorials and found out about `PreparedStatement`. I tried using that as follows (without any other methods):

```
Connection conn = null;
        if(action.getSource() == btnAddItem) 
        {
            try 
            {
            String command = "INSERT INTO item VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


             PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(command);
             preparedStmt.setString (1, itemNo);
             preparedStmt.setString (2, itemName);
             preparedStmt.setDouble (3, costprice);
             preparedStmt.setDouble (4, sellingprice);
             preparedStmt.setInt    (5, stock);


             preparedStmt.execute();
            // conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Now, i have a small hunch that my `Connection conn = null` is the problem. But i cannot figure out what else to set it to. 
I've honestly tried everything i can at this point, and im still new to SQL connection part in java.. so any help or hint you guys can provide is of great help.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Here is the connection method.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException 
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
    connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
            + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/" + this.dbName,
            connectionProps);

    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to open Database connection initialization step.

For example,

```
// JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

//  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

// Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: I've done that part. Lemme edit it to show that part.

Comment: it seems you have initialized conn to null and then you should call getConnection() method to get connection and then you should pass it to executeInsert() method

Comment: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Could it be coz i did the connection in a separate method?

Comment: where are you calling getConnection() method in your code. i am not able to see  it

Comment: in the  Connection getConnection()  method. Should i separately call it every time i insert or update?

Comment: Yes you have to call it everytime when you need connection. You should initialize your connection like Connection conn = yourClass. getConnection();

Comment: Okay, that makes better sense now :) Thanks!